# NoReverseMatch - reverse for ' ' with keyword arguments 'pk' not found

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

im pretty sure this is a simple error but I cant seem to figure it out. The error states that the keyword arguments are not found but i have them in the the html.

here is error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /questions/questionupdate/user2-question3/4/
Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 4}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['questions/questiondetail/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/questionupdate/user2-question3/4/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 4}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['questions/questiondetail/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

file structure:
project: UserTest
--->app:accounts
--->app:questions
```

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_updated']
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="question")
    # completedTODO: get user working^
    question = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False) # unique=True,
    question_html = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    answer = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    answer_html = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default='')
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.question_html = misaka.html(self.question)
        self.answer_html = misaka.html(self.answer)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "questions:detail",
            kwargs={
                # "slug": self.slug,
                "pk": self.pk
            }
        )
```

**urls.py** i am trying to pass both slug and pk to url

```
url(r'questiondetail/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.QuestionDetail.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'questionupdate/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.QuestionUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
```

**views.py**

```
class QuestionDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Question

class QuestionUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = models.Question
    form_class = QuestionForm
    template_name = "questions/question_form_update.html"
```

**question_detail.html**

```
<h3><a href="#">{{ question.user }}</a></h3>
<h3>{{ question.question_html|safe }}</h3>
<h3>{{ question.answer_html|safe }}</h3>
<a href="{% url 'questions:update' slug=question.slug pk=question.pk %}">Update Question</a>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the issue is caused by commented line ;)

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "questions:detail",
            kwargs={
                # "slug": self.slug,
                "pk": self.pk
            }
        )
```

Uncomment it and it should work.

Comment: No problem bro!